# How to remove last 2 months records from 2 years records based on Date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which having 2 years data, need to sort and remove recent 2 months records.

```
Ship_Date        Id

2019-10-29       i1 
2019-10-29       i2
2019-10-28       i3
2019-10-28       i4
....
```

I tried in this way but getting KeyError:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.pop('Ship_Date'))
df.sort_index().last('2M').drop()
```

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.pop('Ship_Date'))
df = df.drop(df.sort_index().last('2M').index)
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael I tried but getting this error: TypeError: 'last' only supports a DatetimeIndex index

Comment: @newbiepandas - also is necessary `df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.pop('Ship_Date'))`